# How to compare the continuous dependent variable with categorical independent variable?

Tags: python, data-science

I would like to know, is there any way to analyze the relation between the continuous dependent variable with categorical independent variable.
I can convert the categorical variable to numeric variable by dummy variable concept. But in some post I read that it is not the appropriate method and need to use T test.
Which Function to use in python to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`scipy` is the package for you, you can find T Test in this [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html).